# Using csom search api, how can I search lists based on content types?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csom, search-api

I have multiple subsites and each subsite has a list called "Articles". Each has two content types. "`News Articles`" and "`Success Stories`". I would like to search based on the content types above using csom search api.

This is my code so far, but I don't get anything back.

```
var queryText = "ContentTypeId:0x010066FA3DE3E334C841B418C82CC475A227";
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("http://dev:5050");
        var contextSite = clientContext.get_site();
        var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(clientContext); 
        keywordQuery.set_queryText(queryText); 
        var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(clientContext);  
        var results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery); 
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess, onQueryError);

        function onQuerySuccess()
        {
            var message = $("#message");
            message.text("Search results fro \"" + queryText + "\"");
            message.append("<br />");
            var rows = results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows;
            $.each(rows, function(index, value)
            {
                message.append(value.Title + ": " + value.Path);
                message.append("<br />");
            });
        }
```

How can I search based on multiple content types?
Or based on specific list name?

**Update**

I found out that by place an asterisk at the end of the content type id 
like so: `0x010066FA3DE3E334C841B418C82CC475A227*`, it works. Now, my question is: Why do I have to place this asterisk at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your updated question, as to why you need an asterisk for it to work:

Because `0x010066FA3DE3E334C841B418C82CC475A227` is an ID of a **site level** content type.  When you add a site content type to a list, SharePoint makes a local copy on the list itself.

From [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms463016(v=office.14).aspx) (emphasis mine):

> In addition, SharePoint Foundation makes a local copy of the site
>   content type and adds the copy to the content type collection on the
>   list. The new list content type is a child of the site content type.
>   **The value of the Id property for the list content type is different from the value of the Id property for its parent site content type**,
>   but otherwise the two content types are initially the same.

List level child content types have IDs that start with the parent site content type ID, plus two zeros (`00`), and then another GUID.  (See [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543822(v=office.14).aspx#sectionSection1) explaining content type IDs and their construction.)

So essentially, *no* list items that are of your content type will have that ID, because items are in lists, and once the content type is copied to the list, it gets a new ID at the list level.

So when you add the asterisk in your search query, you are effectively searching for all items who's content type ID *starts with* the ID specified, which means all *child* content types of the content type who's ID you are specifying.

Which is, of course, exactly what you want.

Comment: yes, that makes sense and I don't know why I had forgotten this fact.