# How to get a list contenttype by contenttype id programmatically?

Tags: content-type

I have for now some code but is not working on all sites because each list has its own listcontenttypeId. It looks like a listcontenttypeId is a combination of the original contenttypeId+[SOMETHING]. What is this thing?? What is the best practice to get the listcontenttype by original contenttypeID?

This is my current code:

```
// list contenttype
            SPList list = curWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Pagina's");
            if (list != null)
            {
                SPContentType listContentType = list.ContentTypes[new SPContentTypeId("0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D003CE876821EAC4EC8AAD81AC501EBCD0700F65D7E6A5FFA6340BA9EE2673A6EA758")];
                if (listContentType != null)
                {
                    SPField listContentTypeField = listContentType.Fields.TryGetFieldByStaticName("ArticleStartDate");
                    if (listContentTypeField != null)
                    {
                        // set this field required
                        listContentType.FieldLinks[listContentTypeField.Id].Required = required;
                        listContentType.Update();
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is the original contenttypeId:
0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D003CE876821EAC4EC8AAD81AC501EBCD07

I dont know where this is comming from in the listcontenttypeId:
00F65D7E6A5FFA6340BA9EE2673A6EA758

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented this:

```
SPList list = curWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Pagina's");
            if (list != null)
            {
                IList<SPContentType> contentTypes = list.ContentTypes.Cast<SPContentType>().Where(c => c.Id.IsChildOf(ctId)).ToList();
                foreach (SPContentType listContentType in contentTypes)
                {
                    if (listContentType != null)
                    {
                        SPField listContentTypeField = listContentType.Fields.TryGetFieldByStaticName("ArticleStartDate");
                        if (listContentTypeField != null)
                        {
                            // set this field required
                            listContentType.FieldLinks[listContentTypeField.Id].Required = required;
                            listContentType.Update();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see [my answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/154189/8992) to another question for some further explanation, but basically what is happening is that when you use a content type on a list, SharePoint makes a local copy of the content type on that list, and the list level content type gets its own ID.

Here is an MSDN article on [Site vs. List level content types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms463016(v=office.14).aspx).

In addition, the way child content types get IDs is by using the parent content type ID, appending "00", and then appending a GUID.

Here is an MSDN article about [Content Type ID structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543822(v=office.14).aspx).

By the looks of the content type ID you are showing as the "original", it looks like a document content type that already has four levels of inheritance before it gets to the list:

Document: `0x0101`

Your first custom document: `0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2`

Your second document (inheriting from first):
`0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39`

Your third (inheriting from second):
`0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D`

Your fourth (inheriting from third):
`0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D003CE876821EAC4EC8AAD81AC501EBCD07`

Your list level content type (child of 4th):
`0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D003CE876821EAC4EC8AAD81AC501EBCD0700F65D7E6A5FFA6340BA9EE2673A6EA758`

Some useful methods to use when trying to work with list level content types when you don't know the ID at the list level and only know the ID of the parent are on the [`SPContentTypeID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeId_members.aspx) class: `BestMatch`, `IsChildOf`, and `IsParentOf`.

In your particular case you could do something like this:

```
SPList list = curWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Pagina's");
if (list != null)
{
    SPContentTypeId parentID = new SPContentTypeId("the parent ID that you know");
    SPContentType listContentType = null;
    foreach (SPContentType potentialChild in list.ContentTypes)
    {
        if (potentialChild.Id.IsChildOf(parentID))
        {
            listContentType = potentialChild;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (listContentType != null)
    {
        SPField listContentTypeField = listContentType.Fields.TryGetFieldByStaticName("ArticleStartDate");
        if (listContentTypeField != null)
        {
            // set this field required
            listContentType.FieldLinks[listContentTypeField.Id].Required = required;
            listContentType.Update();
        }
    }
}
```